# Update postgis table with spatial join subquery

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I maintain two postgis tables: "track_points" and "buffers". The "track_point" table contains a huge amount (almost one billion) of points and the "buffer" table contains about 20 polygons.

What I want to do is, check for all points in which buffer they are contained and assign the respective buffer id to the point record. After searching the web, I found out that "spatial joints" might be a big help here. Based on what I found on the web I put together a query that looks like this ({schema} is just a placeholder for the schema name):

```
WITH join_query AS (
  SELECT
    points.id AS point_id,
    buffers.profile_id AS profile_id
  FROM {schema}.buffers AS buffers
  JOIN {schema}.track_points AS points
  ON ST_Contains(buffers.geom, points.geom)
)

UPDATE {schema}.track_points
  SET profile_id = join_query.profile_id
  FROM join_query
  WHERE id = join_query.point_id
```

I ran the query, but none of the profile_id values in the track_points table has changed. So I guess there must be something wrong with my query?!??

Also, does someone has advice how to achieve my goal more efficiently (with regard to the huge amount of points in the track_points table)?

By the way, I'm using Python's psycopg2 to connect to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your point table is billion of records don't even try to update it - or you can if you can wait few days/weeks to end this update ;). For such kind of mass operation perfect solution is CTAS (create table as select);
I assume that your polygons don't intersect each other, if yes then tell me profile_id of which buffer you want (max, min....);

```
create table track_points2 as
select your_columns_for_track_points(expect profile_id), b.profile_id 
  from track_points tp, buffers b
 where st_dwithin(tp.geom, b.geom,0);
```

Next, drop existing table track_points and replace it with your new one;

```
drop table track_points;
alter table track_points2 alter rename to track_points;
```

And create all needed indexes and constraints for your new table.

If you cannot drop tables, alter tables etc in your database then, of course, you will have to update but be ready for long waiting.

```
 update track_points tp
    set profile_id=b.profile_id
   from buffers b
  where st_dwithin(tp.geom, b.geom,0);
```

As i write before if you have intersecting buffers/polygons then you will have to change update to get what you want from many choices of profile_id.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna give your suggestion a try. Thanks for the quick response! Anyway, is there any reason you use ST_DWithin instead of ST_Contains? Both use bounding box checks, so I thought they should have similar performance.

Comment: I like st_dwithin() - I don't have to care what is inside of what ;)  Also I use it often in my queries when i have to find things that are within or touch, or start inside . with st_dwithin i can find all of them at once and don't have to use 3 different conditions.
But of course in your case with points and polygons st_dwithin() with 0 distance is logically equal to st_contains().
If it helps don't forget to vote or accept :P

Comment: So I tested both queries: the UPDATE version and the CTAS version. Surprisingly, both version take about the same time, roughly 2 hours for 140 million points. The update version is even a little bit faster since I don't have to create indexes. Anyway, for the next processing steps its easier to work with a table that has only the mapped points in it, so I decided to go with the CTAS version! Still, I wonder a little bit why the UPDATE version is so "fast"...

Comment: How many records were updated from this 140M. If this was less then 2% it will be probably faster to update then CTAS. But I don't believe if you update the majority of 140M that CTAS would not be at least 10 times faster then normal update.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! It was only about 3-4% of the points that was updated.

Comment: One more thing - do you have gist index on geom column?

Comment: Yes, I have. (I have accepted your answer already a few days ago...)